# When a sql result contains multiple rows, how can I fetch each row individually from it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

When I send a query to my SQL database and it returns more than one row, how can I fetch each row individually? I've been failing without any result for hours.

For example:

There is a table, which contains names (fore- and surname):

Hans Hansen
Hans Petersen
Peter Petersen

My query looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE forename = 'Hans'";
```

I tried to use mysql_result(), but this function only returns one field. I thought about creating a second function, which is based on mysql_result() *(counting columns -> for Loop to create array)*, but I made some research and many people say, mysql_result() is very slow, when your result gets bigger.

How can I store the result in different arrays for each row in a fast way to finally create a goodlooking table?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: I think, this doesn't work, when result contains more than one row, does it?

Comment: You really should read the manuals. Call it once for each row. There's an example on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: thanks, I didn't know, this is possible with the function. Next time I'll check the documentation first, before I ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are using but I guess a mysql database with the old php mysql functions than you use this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names WHERE forename = 'Hans'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "$row[forename] - $row[sirname] - etc. <br>";
}
```

I also guess you're new to php and did not understand any of this yet but the question you asked is asked multiple times and already answered so try to search and learn before asking this kind of simple questions.

Also you probably asked yourself why declare a variable inside a where loop. The while loop gets the response from `mysql_fetch_assoc`. When it is false it stops but everytime there is a row it will return an array. Well the array is assigned to the variable `$row` and does not affect the loop (try not putting `$row =` and see it still loops). You can then just use the array values and after every spin the mysql result pointer will move one row further. At the last row the function `mysql_fetch_assoc` will move and see there is no result and it will return false. The loop stops and continues to the next line of php code.

Comment: so you say "old php functions", which way do you prefer? :)

Comment: It is advised to use PDO or MYSQLI - http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php - http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php - To say it easy: 'Just read a lot of documentation'

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $results[] = $row;
}
```